# Science fiction book I read in the 1980's, set during WW3, whose cover picture featured a dirigible aircraft carrier

Tags: story-identification

I often think about this book and have never been able to remember the author or title.

The premise as I recall was some sort of world war 3 type situation (possibly a nuclear exchange) where a teenager was separated from his family.   He ended up traveling with some women he met on the road in a electric car (like bronco or SUV?)  I remember the detail about them charging going down hills etc.

The cover of the book was a picture of a Dirigible with a landing strip on it and airplanes taking off.

I believe the ending was the kid who is now a older man sitting on a park bench in the sun (some details about inflation and the price of a bag of potato chips) essentially waiting to die because he could no longer afford to live.

Comment: God, I _so_ wanted this to be _The Warlord of the Air_ by Michael Moorcock.